# Maclaurin series of $e^x\sin x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Would you mind showing me a faster way of building Maclaurin series of
$$f(x)=e^x\sin x$$
so I do not need to calculate a lot of derivatives?

Comment: Will suffice the first 2-3 or so summands of the series?

Comment: Maybe try multiplying each series?

Comment: @Joanpemo 4-5 but anyway would me painful deriving so many times, I thought about multiplying series as the Hunter said but I think I did it wrong

Comment: @VitorCosta That's exactly what I did: to multiply...but only the first $\;4\;$ summands. Inductively any summand can be calculated that way, but right now I've no time (and, honestly, neither the will) to try to come up with the analytic expression for the whole product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6+\ldots\\{}\\\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^5}{120}-\ldots\end{cases}\;\;\implies\;\;e^x\sin x=x+x^2+\frac13x^3-\frac1{30}x^5+\ldots$$

Comment: Anyway I could do it finding directly the general term for the sum?

Comment: @VitorCostaYes, you can try to find out the general term...but that can be pretty tough, although maybe in this case or that it can be more or less easy.

Answer (score 4):

Expand $\mathrm e^{(1+\mathrm i)x}$ and keep the imaginary part of the expansion:
$$\mathrm e^{(1+\mathrm i)x}=1+(1+\mathrm i)x+ \frac{2\mathrm i}{2!} x^2+\frac{2(-1+\mathrm i)}{3!} x^3-\frac{x^4}6+\frac{4(1+\mathrm i)}{5!}x^5+\frac{8\mathrm i}{6!}x^6+\dotsm$$

Comment: I wanted to post this (but after sorting through the coefficients and exponents and doing as much cancellation as possible, quite easy working modulo $8$). But work intervened. I'll +1 your answer instead. The advantage of this method is that it more easily allows the general term to be calculated.

Comment: I agree with you: complexifying a problem is often simpler